# Link that open modal and callto in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i'm now developping a crm application that allow to user to make voip call in dashbord 
i have a probleme that a link should open me a bootstrap  modal and make call using xlite softpohone .
to make call

```
<a href="callto:XXXXXX">XXXXXX</a>
```

to open 
modal

```
<a id="start" data-toggle="modal" href="#static"  onclick="start();">
    <font color="#39d179">
        <span class='icon icon-call-end'></span>
    </font>
</a>
```

[image]

Can anyone give me solution how to slove this problem to make a link that open softphone using callto and open the modal in the same time

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:
Either combine both, and move the modal selector to `data-target` attribute instead of `href`

```
<a href="callto:XXXXXX" id="start" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#static" 
   onclick="start();">
    <font color="#39d179">
        <span class='icon icon-call-end'></span>
    </font>
</a>
```

or programatically open the modal :

```
$(document).on('click', '#start', function(){
    $('#static').modal('open');
    start();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the modal appear but the softphone does not excute

Comment: @EMIN Wled 7ouma rana sa7bi, normal :P